# Query log in codeigniter using hook

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, hook

I need to create a query log in my project. So I created a `post_controller` hook. It saves all the executed queries in both a text file and a database. But it works only for `SELECT` queries. I know it is repeated question, but after a lot of search, I couldn't find solution.

Here is my code:

config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
    'class' => 'LogQueryHook',
    'function' => 'log_queries',
    'filename' => 'log_queries.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

hooks/log_queries.php

```
class LogQueryHook {

function log_queries() {   
    $CI =& get_instance();             
    $times = $CI->db->query_times;
    //$dbs    = array();
    $output = NULL;     
    $queries = $CI->db->queries;
    //print_r($queries);
    if (count($queries) == 0){
        $output .= "no queries\n";
    }else{
        foreach ($queries as $key=>$query){
            $took = round(doubleval($times[$key]), 3);
            $CI->db->query('INSERT INTO queryLog_tbl(`query`, `executedTime`, `timeTaken`, `executedBy`) VALUES ("'.$query.'", "'.date('Y-m-d h:i:s').'", "'.$took.'","'.$CI->session->userdata('UserID').'")');
            $output .= $query . "\n";                
            $output .= "===[took:{$took}]\n\n";
        }

    }

    $CI->load->helper('file');
    if ( ! write_file(APPPATH  . "/logs/queries.log.txt", $output, 'a+')){
         log_message('debug','Unable to write query the file');
    }   
}
}
```

and hooks enabled in my config.php : `$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your internal redirection after any modification query(Insert, Update or delete query) executed. If you put any redirect statement after modification query then it will overtake hook execution.

You can do it by overwriting the `query()` method in `system/database/DB_driver.php`

Or

Create library and call it from relevant controllers.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I created library for the same as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

My code skipping all queries other than `SELECT` because of internal redirection. So I created a library for this. I am attaching my code here. It may help someone else

application/libraries/Querylog.php

```
class Querylog {
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct() {        
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    function save_query_in_db() {
        $query = $this->CI->db->last_query();
        $times = $this->CI->db->query_times; 
        $time = round(doubleval($times[2]), 5);
        $this->CI->db->query('INSERT INTO queryLog_tbl(`query`, `executedTime`, `timeTaken`, `executedBy`) '
            . 'VALUES ("'.$query.'", "'.date('Y-m-d h:i:s').'", "'.$time.'","'.$this->CI->session->userdata('UserID').'")');
    }
}
```

load this library in your controller or autoload.php

and call `save_query_in_db()` where ever you want

eg: in model :

```
$this->db->set('status', 1);
$this->db->where('UserID', $this->session->userdata('UserID'));
$this->db->update('user_tbl');
$this->querylog->save_query_in_db();
```